# Question about shelving/unshelving in TFS

Tags: tfs, shelving

when you shelve / unshelve items in TFS, is it private? That is, can other people see what i've shelved and even unshelve that?

If it is public, is it possible to make it private?

Answer (score 2):

Shelve sets are public.
As far as I can find you can not make them private.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check to see if this has changed at all in VS2010.